# Images are not aligned correctly in IE

Tags: php, html, css

A friend of mine has a website and recently we have got a few messages saying that the certain set of images were not aligned properly in IE or firefox so i assume the error is to do with google chrome but unsure.

Here is the link to the website: [niftymodz.com - Xbox Creation Station](http://niftymodz.com/Store/index.php/xbox-creation-station.html)

I would be glad if someone help me with the issue.

Please let me know what other information can I provide in order to improve my question.

Comment: Please do not link to your web site. Why?
[This is why.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Answer (score 0):

just a basic answer that usually solves alot of problems and might solve yours as well:

every browser has its default styling. called user-agent style.

you need to reset all elements first and then work on them.

create a a new style sheet name it reset.css and link it to your website before other style sheets, and in it reset everything.
here is something to assist:

```
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/

    html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
```

source: [Here](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)